# JS, сортировка массива, по значениями другого массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите, как сделать сортировка одного простого массива, по значениям другого?
Массив для сравнения:

```
let array_1 = ['john', 'michael', 'hugh', 'jack', 'andrew', 'vince', 'stewie'];
let array_2 = ['jack', 'michael', 'andrew'];
```

Подскажите, как отсортировать так, чтобы получилось:

```
console.log(array_2); // ['michael', 'jack', 'andrew'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array_1 = ['john', 'michael', 'hugh', 'jack', 'andrew', 'vince', 'stewie'];
let array_2 = ['jack', 'michael', 'andrew'];

array_2.sort((a, b) => array_1.indexOf(a) - array_1.indexOf(b))
console.log(array_2)
```